# less conditional / guard to check for element:active?

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I have a list item that contains a link inside. I've styled the list item be a link itself and has css properties `:active` enabled to make it appear to be clicked. However, I would like that to *not* happen when I'm clicking the link inside it as to not be confusing where the user is actually ending up.

before I changed anything:

```
.store-list-item:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

after trying with guards:

```
.store-list-item:active when not (.store-list-item .make-default:active) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Is this possible? If not, any workarounds?

**EDIT: I Added a jsfiddle of what's exactly happening.**
http://jsfiddle.net/cV8ep/1/

Comment: Not sure this is possible - it would have to translate to CSS as not applying the box shadow when the `a` is active, which means a parent selector would be required, which does not exist.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yet. I still hope that the [subject selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) will make it into some implementations someday.

Comment: @Zeta: Maybe within the year if we get lucky!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Workaround

If you apply your styling that is currently on the `li` instead to a new wrapper `div` that will be inside that `li`, a wrapper which contains *all but* the "Make Default" button, then apply a `position: relative` on the `li` and a `position: absolute` on the button to position it back over the wrapper in about the same place, this will disassociate the button from being in the wrapper that gets the `:active` state (which is now that new wrapper `div`, not the `li`). This will prevent the activation of the effect on the click of the button.

[**See this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cV8ep/5/) (which has a few "hacky" points to it, like I just overrode the `.pull-right` class for the sake of illustration; you would want to be a bit more elegant about the actual construction of the code).

Comment: Thanks; it'll do for what I need it to. I can only hope we can get more sophisticated logic support in a future release.

Comment: @OnResolve: If your desire is for "logic support" in LESS, that is not the issue. The problem is CSS has no means of selecting what you desire (you basically want to select the parent element based off the child element's state). LESS is only a preprocessor for producing a CSS selector, and so it has the ultimate limitation of what ever type of selectors CSS allows.